# facebook - must be a URL with a valid domain

Tags: facebook, appmobi

I created a small facebook application using intel XDK. built the application for facebook choose to host with appmobi due to the https which i need for facebook.

But when i enter my canvas url to facebook i get this error.

```
must be a URL with a valid domain.
```

Could this be due to how appMobi create your link for your application because mine is

```
Kx810CVywlL-Join6agZKoAtDMPD_Hmo1531LVccvY.appmobi.net
```

I have tried with and without http:// - https://, but i am still getting the error?

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have underscores in a domain name.

Kx810CVywlL-Join6agZKoAtDMPD_Hmo1531LVccvY.appmobi.net

Comment: just noticed that, Thank you... But how come appMobi put underscore in the domain when i'm trying to put the application on facebook??

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with appmobi, obviously it doesnt work as a URL, maybe contact their tech support?